# Testing calling of method on injected Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, factory, karma-jasmine

Trying to figure out how check wether a method on an injected Service is being called.

The Service (based on Factory): loginService.js

```
angular.module('loginService', [])
    .factory('loginService', function (URLbase, $http, loginModel, $route, $location, logoutService, overviewService) {
        return {
            logMeIn: function (login) {

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: URLbase + 'authentication/login',
                    data: {'Login': login.username, 'Password': login.password}
                }).then(function (result) {

                        loginModel.set('passwordRequested', false);
                        loginModel.set('loginFailed', false);
                        loginModel.set('loginExpired', false);
                        loginModel.set('loginBlocked', false);
                        loginModel.set('loggedIn', false);
                        loginModel.set('sessionExpired', false);
                        loginModel.set('loggedIn', false);
                        loginModel.set('concurrentLogin', false);
                        loginModel.set('somethingWrong', false);

                        // Check login result by status code
                        var status = result.data.Response.Status.StatusCode,
                            data = result.data.Response.Payload;

                    switch (status) {
                        case 0:
                            loginModel.set('tokenToken', data.Token);
                            loginModel.set('tokenUserId', data.userId);
                            loginModel.set('userName', data.User.FirstName + ' ' + data.User.SurName);
                            loginModel.set('userFirstName', data.User.FirstName);
                            loginModel.set('userLastName', data.User.SurName);
                            loginModel.set('userEmailAddress', data.User.Email);
                            loginModel.set('userPhone', data.User.Phone);
                            loginModel.set('userPreferredLanguage', data.User.PreferredLanguage);
                            loginModel.set('loggedIn', true);
        ......
```

The Unit test

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, $injector, _loginService_, _loginModel_) {
    loginService = _loginService_;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    loginModel = _loginModel_;

    loginPost = {'Login': login.username, 'Password': login.password};
    httpBackend.whenPOST(URLbase + 'authentication/login', loginPost).respond(200, jsonObj);
}));

it('should get login data from the backend', function () {

    spyOn(loginService, 'logMeIn').andCallThrough();
    loginService.logMeIn(login);
    expect(loginService.logMeIn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(login);
    httpBackend.flush();

    //spyOn(loginModel, 'set').andCallThrough();
    //loginService >> logMeIn >> loginModel.set('userLastName', 'Vijver');
    //metod >> toHaveBeenCalledWith('userLastName', 'Vijver');
});
```

So in the last 3 commented lines I want to test if `loginModel.set('userFirstName', data.User.FirstName);` is being called with the correct paramaters.

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the result inside the call itself:

```
logService.logMeIn(login).then(function(result) {
  expect(loginModel.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith('userFirstName',data.User.FirstName);
});
```

**EDIT**

Your function should do this:

```
return {
        logMeIn: function (login) {

            return $http({..
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

In regards to your switch statements I'd do this as I like to keep the success and failure parts as small as possible:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: URLbase + 'authentication/login',
  data: {'Login': login.username, 'Password': login.password}
}).then(function (result) {

  // This underscore is lodash syntax - which I'd recommend
  var loginStuff = ['passwordRequested','loginFailed','loginExpired',etc];
  _.forEach(loginDetails, function(detail) {
    loginModel.set(detail, false);
  });
  // Here I have immediately removed lines of redundant code.
  // I'd also suggest you go one further and place this into it's own    
  // function - which can be private to the service if you choose
});
```

This same principal can be applied to the switch. Without seeing all of the switch cases I can't properly refactor it.

Comment: makes sense, implemented it, butI get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @SanJayFalcon that's because you aren't returning a promise. Change your logMeIn() function to return it. See my edit

Comment: this works, but, the function 'loginModel.set' exists in a certain switch case. I am forcing the code to run through a different switch case now which doesn't contain this function but still the test succeeds. `loginModel.set` seems to be tested stand alone, it needs to be tested as a property on loginService?

Comment: @SanJayFalcon I'd suggest moving the code outside of the switch block so it can be properly tested. If it only exists inside a switch block then 1 - the switch block becomes too large, 2 - harder to test. In theory - testing things should be easy if the code is written with succinct principals applied

Comment: I don't see how to do that. There are 5 cases on which the login procedure should react. Switch or if/else implementation seems logical. Can you be a it more precise on how you see it?

Comment: Mostly interested in how a different implementation improves testability and why a Switch maybe isn't the est implementation for good testable code.